# How to set intel vga to maximum memory?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, integrated-graphics

I am using Windows 7 ultimate x64 bit with ram 8gb. But my Intel HD IGP is showing only 68 mb. I have problem with gaming as before it would show 1084mb of memory. Can you suggest me how to set some memory to it?

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible, then it will be in the BIOS menu. When your computer starts up, try pressing "DEL" (that's the most common key) and enter the BIOS.

Then use your motherboard's manual to find the option. It will go by the name "Shared memory" and such. (You can also get a manual for your motherboard's from the manufacturer's website.)

Comment: But I doubt you could play a game that needs about ~1gb of VRAM. You will need some more serious VGA for that.